# c# display the value to listview if 3 button is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

can someone help me on my problem I'm making an ordering system for our thesis and I don't know what to do next if 3 button is clicked

Things I want to happen:
user need to pick an item first then he/she will pick a quantity for the item(I have 10 buttons for quantity: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)

so I add a `button0` so the user need to pick item and then click `button1` then `button0` to have a quantity of 10 that will display in my `listview`

1-9 button is working now but my problem is what if the user wants the item for a quantity of 10 or more

so here I have my code for an item `button1`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ms = 1;
}
```

and the quantity button

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ms == 1)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(btnms1.Text);
        item.SubItems.Add("1");
        item.SubItems.Add("118");
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        ms = 0;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //working
}
```

here is the 0 `button`

```
private void button0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // magic please
}
```

Comment: What if user want `20+` items  or even more?

Comment: i will use the logic of the accepted answer

Comment: From usability point of view, the User needs to enter a quantity (pressing the buttons [0-9]+) and then press another button to accept the input, the input then can be treated as a whole number quantity the user wants to buy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but it might be something like this.

[image: Sample Form]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "1";
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "2";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "3";
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "4";
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "5";
    }

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "6";
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "7";
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "8";
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "9";
    }

    private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += "0";
    }

    private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int quantity = 0;

        bool quantityParse = int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out quantity);

        string productName = "Product Name"; // Sample Name
        double productPrice = 300; // Sample Price

        if (quantityParse)
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(productName); // Name
            lvi.SubItems.Add(quantity.ToString()); // Quantity
            lvi.SubItems.Add(productPrice.ToString()); // Price
            lvi.SubItems.Add((productPrice * quantity).ToString()); // Subtotal
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add a clear button to set the quantity back to 0. I forgot to add this though..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please start picking more meaningful names for variables as they help with code comprehension, especially when your code gets too complex for you or when you are sharing with others.

Secondly, how you're doing this at the moment is not the most intuitive way to go about things, always aim for the least amount of code as possible.

What I would be doing is calling the same event handler for each of the quantity buttons, but parsing the text in the buttons as a integer and adding that to a total string.

Ie:

```
private string QuantityText = string.Empty;

private void QtyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button) 
    {
      Button theButton = (Button)sender;
      string qtyText = theButton.Content.ToString();
      QuantityText += qtyText;
    }
}
```

Then call something like this method when you want to process the quantity string:

```
Private Void ProcessQuantity()
{
  int qtyAmount = -1;
  int.TryParse(QuantityText, out qtyAmount)
  if (qtyAmount > -1)
  {
   //Do Processing here
  }
  else
  {
    throw new InvalidArgumentException("Quantity is invalid");
  }
}
```